# How to access multiple models from a controller

Tags: node.js, heroku, model, geddy

I have a Locations model and a Recorders model. I want to be able to pass all of the data for both data sets to my view model. How can I access them though because I think they're not in scope since I'm getting undefined errors because I'm calling 'all'

https://gist.github.com/3998302

```
var Main = function () {
  this.index = function (req, resp, params) {
    var self = this;
    var data = {};
    geddy.model.Locations.all(function(err, locations) {
        data.locations = locations;
        geddy.model.Recorders.all(function(err, recorders) {
            data.recorders = recorders;
            self.respond({params: params, data: data}, {
            format: 'html'
            , template: 'app/views/locations/index'
            }
        });
    }););
  };

};

exports.Main = Main;
```

Error snippet:

```
timers.js:103
            if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
                                                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'all' of undefined
    at index (G:\code\PeopleTracker\app\controllers\main.js:23:24)
    at controller.BaseController._handleAction.callback (C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\base_
controller.js:387:22)
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're initializing the `data` variable to 'undefined'. Try `data = {}` instead. If that doesn't fix it, I'll do some troubleshooting with you.

**EDIT**

If that doesn't do it for you, try installing geddy again:

`npm uninstall -g geddy && npm install -g geddy`

If that doesn't do it, make sure that your DB is actually running, make sure that the models are defined (try `geddy console` to check your models), and make sure that you're on the latest stable version of node.

Comment: Correct: JavaScript doesn't "autovivify" objects the way that, say, Perl does. Assigning a property to an `undefined` variable doesn't automatically turn the variable into an object references.

Comment: I changed that and it still gives me an error.

    timers.js:103
                if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
                                                                          ^
    TypeError: Cannot call method 'all' of undefined
        at index (G:\code\PeopleTracker\app\controllers\main.js:23:24)
        at controller.BaseController._handleAction.callback (C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\base_
    controller.js:387:22)

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but I believe you can just call

```
geddy.model.Locations.all(function(err, locations) {
    geddy.model.Recorders.all(function(err, recorders) {
        var data = {};
        data.locations = locations;
        data.recorders = recorders;
        self.respond({params: params, data: data}, {
        format: 'html'
        , template: 'app/views/locations/index'
        }
    });
}););
```

You could also have the respond say

```
self.respond({params: params, locations: locations, recorders: recorders});
```

but if you want all of that data available from the data literal you need it defined in the lowest scope callback. The callbacks can read above their scope but they cannot write above it.